# In JPA which type of parameter is better to use "positional/named"?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

With Hibernate as provider.

In terms of performance (or others), **which type of parameter is better to use?**
 and **why?**

*Positional*

```java
TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery
  ("FROM Client c WHERE c.clientId = ?1",Client.class);
query.setParameter(1, clientId);
```

or *Named*

```java
TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery
  ("FROM Client c WHERE c.clientId = :clientId",Client.class);
query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
```

Comment: I have never listened to any study about this kind of comparison, but I would like to see the data sources and process about it if they exists.

Comment: "Performance" is *not* a useful consideration here. So, use the form that is more clear. This can change from query to query. Positional in an `INSERT ... VALUES` might make most sense, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be really considering performance in this case, **named parameters helps in  improving the readability of the code**. Even if it is slower by few **nano second** or so you should be sticking to it.

```
TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery
  ("FROM Client c WHERE c.clientId = :clientId",Client.class);
query.setParameter("clientId", clientId);
```

In the above lines it is very clear that you are setting the value for `clientId`. **It is simple, crisp and clear and that how you want to code**.

Comment: Moreover, using named parameters makes HQL/JPQL query refactoring a lot easier and less error-prone than with positional parameters