# SetParametres in Query

Tags: jakarta-ee, sessionfactory, createquery

I'm trying to set a query with lot of parameters.

for a query with 1 param its working fine:

```
//**
    List<?> list = null;
    String query = String.format("from %s where %s = :%s ", a, uniqueField[0], uniqueField[0]);
    list = s.createQuery(query).setParameter(uniqueField[0], arg0.getSsn()).list();
```

how can i do the same with this query :

```
List<?> list = null;
String query = String.format("from %s where %s = :%s and %s = :%s ", a, uniqueField[0], uniqueField[0], uniqueField[1], uniqueField[1]);
// list = s.createQuery(query)... ?
```

Thanks for any advices..

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a database API?

Comment: @Nicholas i'm using Hibernate

Comment: Just name the parameters then: ":param1", ":param2". Then q.setParameter(":param1", value1).setParam(":param2", value2) ...

Comment: @Nicholas can u post it as an answer so i can commit it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a query, you can either use named parameters or positional parameters. Named parameters are pretty easy, I'm not sure what the performance implications are:

So, just name the parameters then: ":param1", ":param2". Then q.setParameter(":param1", value1).setParam(":param2", value2).

Reference:  
[In JPA which type of parameter is better to use “positional/named”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309314/in-jpa-which-type-of-parameter-is-better-to-use-positional-named)